# Automatic page breaks while printing to pdf from Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Here is VBA I use to automatically insert page breaks while printing to pdf. Code seems to work if there is more than one page. However if there is only page in document debugger gives an error

> Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range

pointing to `Set r = PrintVersion.Cells(.Item(pb).Location.Row, 1)`. Any ideas what is the problem and how to repair it?

Here is my code:

```
    Sub Print()

        Dim Cell As Range
        Dim tempFolderPath As String
        Dim filePath As String
        Dim fileTitle As String
        Dim fnd As Range, r As Range, pb As Variant
        Dim PrintVersion As Worksheet
        Dim WData As Worksheet
        Dim rw As Range, hideRange As Range

        Set PrintVersion = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print version")
        Set WData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

        With PrintVersion.Range("Print_Area")

                With .Cells.Rows
                    .WrapText = True
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .EntireRow.AutoFit
                End With

' Hide blank rows with formulas giving as a result ""
        For Each rw In .Rows
            For Each Cell In rw.Cells
                If Cell.HasFormula Then
                    If Cell.Value = "" Then
                        If Not rw.Hidden Then
                            If hideRange Is Nothing Then
                                Set hideRange = rw
                            Else
                                Set hideRange = Union(hideRange, rw)
                            End If
                            Exit For    ' no need to process rest of the row
                       End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
        If Not hideRange Is Nothing Then hideRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End With

' Set print area till the last cell
        PrintVersion.PageSetup.PrintArea = PrintVersion.Range("A1:C" & _
        PrintVersion.[LOOKUP(2,1/(C1:C250<>""),ROW(C1:C250))]).Address


           ' make sure sheet is in page break view
            PrintVersion.Parent.Windows(1).View = xlPageBreakPreview

        ' first clear any set page breaks
        PrintVersion.ResetAllPageBreaks

        ' move preposed breaks to top of segement
        With PrintVersion.HPageBreaks

            pb = 1
            Do
                ' check if first column is empty
                Set r = PrintVersion.Cells(.Item(pb).Location.Row, 1)
                If r.Value = "" Then
                    ' find previous cell in column 1 which is not empty
                    Set fnd = PrintVersion.Columns(1).Find("*", r, , , , xlPrevious)
                    ' set page break 1 row above it
                    Set .Item(pb).Location = fnd.Offset(-1, 0)
                    DoEvents

                End If
                pb = pb + 1
                If pb > .Count Then Exit Do
            Loop
        End With

        ' create a path for a temporary file
        tempFolderPath = Environ("Temp")
        fileTitle = "CV_" & Sheets("Filling form").Range("F7") & "_" & Sheets("Filling form").Range("F9")
        filePath = tempFolderPath & "\" & fileTitle & ".pdf"

        PrintVersion.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, filePath, xlQualityStandard, True, , , , False

        Set PrintVersion = Nothing
        Set WData = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if there are no pagebreaks you do not need to handle them, right? Check if there are any before going into it:

```
 With PrintVersion.HPageBreaks
    If .Count > 0 Then
        pb = 1
        Do
            ' check if first column is empty
            Set r = PrintVersion.Cells(.Item(pb).Location.Row, 1)
            If r.Value = "" Then
                ' find previous cell in column 1 which is not empty
                Set fnd = PrintVersion.Columns(1).Find("*", r, , , , xlPrevious)
                ' set page break 1 row above it
                Set .Item(pb).Location = fnd.Offset(-1, 0)
                DoEvents

            End If
            pb = pb + 1
            If pb > .Count Then Exit Do
        Loop
    End If
End With
```

(not tested)